# Set secondary zone in Cloud SQL (MySQL) High Availability instance via Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql, high-availability

my goal is set `primary` and `secondary zone` in `Google Cloud SQL` instance using `terraform`. It can be easily done using UI, but I would like to achieve this using `terraform`.

In the `terraform` documentation [google_sql_database_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance) there is option to set `primary zone` using `settings.location_preference.location` which allows to set **Primary Zone**, but I am not able to configure **Secondary Zone** or find any examples.

I've tried to use `list type` but terraform is expecting only 1 string for `location_preference.location`. I also tried some kind of workaround to use `follow_gae_application` but as I don't have `Google App Engine` application it also resulted in error.

Any ideas if this is possible or there are any workarounds?

**EDIT:**
I already set `availability_type` to `Regional`. When creating Cloud SQL instance, it creates `Primary zone` with zone mentioned in `preferred_location`, but `secondary zone` is set randomly (sometimes is `-a`, sometimes is `-b` or `-d`.

Regarding `settings.backup_configuration.location` it's where **backup** of `Cloud SQL` instance will be created. Expected value is 'region' so (`eu`, `us` or `asia`).

Comment: I was reading the documentation and found out that you need to set `settings. availability_type` to `REGIONAL`, also it states that `settings.backup_configuration.enabled` must be set to true as well, I'm inferring that the secondary zone will be the one you specify under `settings.backup_configuration.location`

Comment: Thanks @kornshell93 for your reply, but this is something different. I will elaborate this in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [google_sql_database_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance) module has been updated.

Currently, the `settings.location_preference` block supports new argument:

**secondary_zone** - (Optional) The preferred Compute Engine zone for the secondary/failover.

Previously there were only arguments **follow_gae_application** and **zone**.